# Custom CSS to Change Bookdown Page Width

Tags: css, r-markdown, bookdown

At the risk of getting a couple of down votes, I have to ask this after spending a few hours this afternoon trying to unravel the css of the bookdown html document that I am working on.  For the life of me I just cannot figure out the selectors to use to increase the max-width of the main text area of the bookdown document.  I am working with some content that would really benefit from using more of my large monitors.

My latest attempt to get the specificity that I need is a custom css file that contains:

```
.book .book-body.fixed .body-inner .page-wrapper .page-inner .normal .section .level1 .unnumbered {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have tried numerous combinations of selectors and I just can't get that max-width to budge from the 800px default.

For testing purposes, [here is an example bookdown document.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/)

Comment: You'll have to include your HTML, or at bare minimum a working example, accessible site... something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner {
  max-width: 1200px !important;
}
```

Comment: That got it.  the **!important;** was the bit I was missing.

Comment: where does this .css go?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Generally, the CSS goes into your working directory. But it depends on what you are saying in your _output.yml file. I prefer to collect all CSS files in a separate folder. So I write "css: 'css/mystyle.css'" under my bookdown::gitbook header.

Comment: You can embed the CSS code in your Rmd file between <style> labels. 
``` {=html} 
<style type="text/css"> 
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner {   max-width: 1200px !important; }
</style> 
```